# I don't understand theorem about hermitian operators

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

**Theorem:**
Let $V$ be finite-dimensional inner-product space and $A\in L(V)  $. There exist unique operator $A^*$ such that $\langle Ax,y \rangle=\langle x,A^*y \rangle$ for every $x,y\in V$.

**Proof:** Lets fix $y\in V$ and observe mapping $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle Ax,y \rangle$. We obviously got linear functional on $V$ and by Riesz reprenstation theorem there exist unique vector-whom we will call $A^*y$- such that $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle x,A^*y \rangle$ for every $x\in V$. In other words we have $$\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,A^*y \rangle$$ for every $x\in V$. If we repeat this algorithm for every $y\in V$ we get $$\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,A^*y \rangle$$ for every $x,y\in V$.

The part that I don't understand is if we defined $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle Ax,y \rangle$ how can we lose $Ax$ when we apply Riesz theorem and get $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle x,A^*y \rangle$. I understand Riesz theorem if we have regular linear functionals, but if we defined functional with $Ax$ inside of it how do we lose it.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "losing $A$" here.  $f_{A,y}$ is a linear functional, so why can't we apply Riesz representation?  If we can apply Riesz representation, then what do you think that applying Riesz representation **should** look like?

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that, with the proof as it stands, there is no justification of the fact that the operator $y \mapsto A^*y$ is linear, which is certainly part of the statement here.

Comment: I think that it should look like $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle Ax,A^*y \rangle$

Comment: Second part of proof is proving that $A^*$ is linear but i understand that.

Comment: Okay, but the point of the Riesz representation theorem is to state that we for a functional $f$ and the right vector $v$, we have
$$
f(x) = \langle x, v \rangle \quad \forall x \in V
$$
can you see how that *doesn't* match what you have?

Comment: No. The author considers for each $y\in V$  the linear functionals $f_y\colon x\mapsto \langle Ax,y\rangle$ (which of course depends on $A$). Applying Riesz' representation theorem, we have $f_y(x)=\langle x,z\rangle$ for a unique $z$, which we denote $Ay*$, since it depends on both $y$ and $A$.

Comment: I think i got it.$f_{A,y}(x)=\langle Ax,y \rangle$ is just the way to define a functional. It has values for each x, and we can apply Riesz theorem no matter how we defined it. Even if it was $f_{A,B,y}(x)=\langle B(Ax),y \rangle$ we could still find vector $z$ that satisfies $f_{A,B,y}(x)=\langle x,z \rangle$

Comment: @RushThaMan In that case, we have $$z=(BA)^*y=A^*B^*y$$ Here, $z$ depends on $A,B,y$ because those are the factors affecting the functional.

Comment: @NobleMushtak $y$ instead of $x$ i think

Comment: @RushThaMan you indeed got it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a re-wording of the proof will help you.

Fix $y \in V$ and look at $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle Ax,y \rangle$. By the Riesz representation, we have $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle x,z\rangle$ for some $z \in V$ that depends on $A$ and $y$. Therefore, we can look at it as $f_{A,y}(x)=\langle x, g_A(y) \rangle$ since $g_A(y)$ depends on both $A$ and $y$. Thus, we have:
$$\langle Ax,y \rangle=f_{A,y}(x)=\langle x,g_A(y)\rangle$$
Thus, $g_A$ is the adjoint operator we were looking for, so we write $g_A=A^*$, prove the linearity of $g_A$, and we are done.

Comment: Is that from your linear algebra book? It's interesting how different math colleges have similar proofs for theorems.

Comment: @RushThaMan No, this is me re-writing the proof above in my own words. Does it help you?